# Download image from website that requires authentication/credentials using php

Tags: php

The $source is the url link of an image from a website that requires authentication/login. I was able to download the image but the downloaded image can't be opened. I knew the image is not downloaded properly as it is asking for credentials. I use CURL to download the image and now, I have no idea what's wrong with the code, what else should i add to it??

```
<?php

    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];

    $source = 'https://example.com/sequence.png';

    $fp = fopen('C:/image/'.basename($source), 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($source);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY ) ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");// to use for    connection
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);// content type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);   

    curl_exec($ch);

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I added the 'error_reporting(-1);' line in my code, no errors are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If your authentication is not basic, you need some library like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

You can do the login process and then download the image

Comment: The website would required users to login first before they can view any content. The problem is, when i try to do ctrl+A -> ctrl+C and then paste it on google docs, some of the image can't be display due to authentication. Hence, I am trying to force the browser to download the images after users logged in to the website. Therefore, when the user copy the whole page of the website, the copied image url will be coming from local cached image , not from the website.